# How to pass callback in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, pass-by-reference

Code will explain all:

```
    class ResultOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
    
      final bool _isCorrect;
      VoidCallback _onTap;
    
      ResultOverlay(this._isCorrect, this._onTap);
      ......
      ......
}
```

Its state class:

```
class ResultOverlayState extends State<ResultOverlay>{
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ........
      child: new InkWell(
        onTap: () => widget._onTap,
.....
.....
}
```

Passing of callback function:

```
new ResultOverlay(isCorrect, () {
                        () => CallAnswerPage();
                      })
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was not passing the callback correctly. Here is the correct syntax:

```
new ResultOverlay(
    isCorrect, 
    () => callAnswerPage()
)
```

So silly mistake :)

Answer (score 69):

*This is a more general answer for future viewers.*

### Callback types

There are a few different types of predefined callbacks:

```
final VoidCallback myVoidCallback = () {};
final ValueGetter<int> myValueGetter = () => 42;
final ValueSetter<int> myValueSetter = (value) {};
final ValueChanged<int> myValueSetter = (value) {};
```

**Notes**:

- **VoidCallback** is an anonymous function that takes no arguments and returns no value.
- **ValueGetter** is an anonymous function that returns a value, which you provide for someone who wants to *get* it.
- **ValueSetter** is an anonymous function that takes a value as an argument, which you can use to *set* some other value.
- **ValueChanged** has the same function signature and is used the same way as `ValueSetter`, but its name emphasizes that the given value actually changed (and was not just set with the same value again).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62244979/3681880) for more details.

### Ways to write the callback

#### Good

When you are asked to provide a callback to an API, you can directly write the callback:

```
onPressed: () {},
```

Or you can supply the callback variable name (without parentheses):

```
onPressed: myVoidCallback,
```

#### Less good

It would be unnecessarily verbose to use both forms (but you could if you included the parentheses after the variable name):

```
onPressed: () {
  myVoidCallback();
},
```

This one is equivalent (but also unnecessarily verbose):

```
onPressed: () => myVoidCallback(),
```

Just use one of the "Good" forms from above.

#### Still good

The exception would be if you wanted to do something like call a value setter when the parameter is only asking for a void callback:

```
onPressed: () => myValueSetter(42),
```

Answer (score 10):

Everything is fine beside how you use it.

Change

```
    onTap: () => widget._onTap,
```

to

```
    onTap: widget._onTap,
```

inside your `State` class

Answer (score 1):

```
onTap: () => widget._onTap,
```

as ontap needs function '()=>' itself is a function, So it will be onTap:widget._onTap,

and  if you want to use in stateless widget ontap:_ontap

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests,VoidCallback listens for click events.here is below example.

```
 ResultOverlay(true, _requestPermission);
                  ResultOverlay(_isCorrect, () {
                    print('I am a voidCallback');
                  });
```

or

```
 ResultOverlay(true, _requestPermission);
                      ResultOverlay(_isCorrect, myVoidCallback());
```

ResultOverlay

```
class ResultOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool _isCorrect;
  VoidCallback _onTap;

  ResultOverlay(this._isCorrect, this._onTap);

  @override
  State<ResultOverlay> createState() => _ResultOverlayState();
}

class _ResultOverlayState extends State<ResultOverlay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: widget._onTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```