# Pass method as parameter to a widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a custom button widget:

```
class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  Button(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => {}, // Use the function from parent Widget
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 13),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )),
          color: COLOR_BLUE,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then in parent Widget I want to pass a `onPressed` method to this button widget:

```
...
myMethod () => {
   // do some stuff
}
...
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
    child: Button("Log in", myMethod),
),
...
```

How can I tell a button widget to use the `myMethod` for `onPress`?

Comment: see how it is done for a [RawMaterialButton](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button.dart#L67)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## Use `VoidCallback` type

Check the line comments on the code as well for more information:

```
class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback callback; // Notice the variable type

  Button(this.text, this.callback);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: callback, // Simply put the function name here, DON'T use ()
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 13),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )),
          color: COLOR_BLUE,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- By omitting the parentheses, you are passing the function itself as a parameter. If you added the parentheses, the function would be executed and you would pass the return of the function to the widget.

Then, initialize your widget:

```
Button("Log in", myMethod)
```

or

```
Button("Log in", (){
    print('something');
})
```

Comment: +1. You can also define your own typedefs for methods if you want one that takes parameters and/or returns a result: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs

Comment: Any reason for not putting **()** ? I put **onPressed:(){ callback() ; },** and it still worked fine!?!

Comment: @user3833732 when you add (), you are executing the function and getting the response when the code is run. When you skip the parentheses, you are passing the function as a parameter, as if it was a variable. So onPressed actually takes the function itself, not the result of the function. 
When you put `() { callback(); }` , you are passing a function with one line as a parameter, you are not executing it :) If you use callback(), onPressed will receive nothing (void) as value, because that what it would return.

Comment: Ahh.. thanks! So correct me if Im wrong... Skipping the parenthesis allows us to accept a returning value, (which I think is an Advantage!)... BUT otherwise **() { callback(); }**   will always have a void return.

Comment: VoidCallback is the answer yes , thank you bro

Comment: I get `The values in a const list literal must be constants.
Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.` when I do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 67):

There are a few predefined types that already exist.

## VoidCallback

If you want to create a parameter something like this:

```
onPressed: () { },
```

Then you can define it in your class like so:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  MyWidget({Key key, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  // ...
}
```

#### Notes

The `typedef` is defined in the source code like this:

```
typedef VoidCallback = void Function();
```

The asynchronous version is `AsyncCallback`.

```
typedef AsyncCallback = Future<void> Function();
```

## ValueSetter

If you want to create a parameter something like this:

```
onPressed: (value) { },
```

Then you can define it in your class like so:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  MyWidget({Key key, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  final ValueSetter<String> onPressed;

  // ...
}
```

#### Notes

The typedef is defined in the source code like this:

```
typedef ValueSetter<T> = void Function(T value);
```

If you want to specify that the function only gets called when there is a change then use ValueChanged instead.

```
typedef ValueChanged<T> = void Function(T value);
```

The asynchronous version is `AsyncValueSetter`.

```
typedef AsyncValueSetter<T> = Future<void> Function(T value);
```

## ValueGetter

If you want to create a parameter something like this:

```
onPressed: () => value,
```

Then you can define it in your class like so:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  MyWidget({Key key, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  final ValueGetter<String> onPressed;

  // ...
}
```

#### Notes

The typedef is defined in the source code like this:

```
typedef ValueGetter<T> = T Function();
```

The asynchronous version is `AsyncValueGetter`.

```
typedef AsyncValueGetter<T> = Future<T> Function();
```

## Define your own type

As you can see from all of the examples above, everything is just a `typedef` for a `Function`. So it is easy enough to make your own.

Say you want to do something like this:

```
onEvent: (context, child) => value,
```

Then you would make the typedef like this:

```
typedef MyEventCallback = int Function(BuildContext context, Widget widget);
```

And use it like this:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  MyWidget({Key key, this.onEvent}) : super(key: key);

  final MyEventCallback onEvent;

  // ...
}
```

See the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) for more.

Comment: Say I create a CustomTextField that returns a TextField. How would you make a constructor for the onChanged property and pass it correctly? I'm trying to make a constructor for the CustomTextField that passes the function correctly to the TextField inside. Things would be like onChanged: onChanged.

Comment: @IvánYoed, You can [check out how TextField does it](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/02d441ea55b328133c266991f43b0a1148edb63f/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart) and do the same thing. They have `ValueChanged<String>? onChanged` where `ValueChanged` is defined to be `void Function(T value)`.