# why the screen doesn't update?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello i created a custom BottomNavigation bar with tow IconButton's and i want if I tap on some Icon, that the body of the Scaffold change but it dosen't work.

her is my Cod:

```
int index = 0;

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> page = [
      const HomeScreen(),
      const FolderScreen(),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: page[index],
      bottomNavigationBar: const CustomBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}

enum Pages {
  home,
  folder,
}

class CustomBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomBottomNavigationBar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> createState() =>
      _CustomBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _CustomBottomNavigationBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> {
  Pages selectPage = Pages.home;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return SizedBox(
      width: size.width,
      height: 80.0,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          CustomPaint(
            size: Size(size.width, 80.0),
            painter: BNBCustomPainter(),
          ),
          Center(
            heightFactor: 0.71,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: 1.25,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                elevation: 0.1,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: size.width,
            height: 80.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectPage = Pages.home;
                      index = 0;
                      print(index);
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    color: selectPage == Pages.home
                        ? kActiveBottomNavigationButtonColor
                        : kInactiveBottomNavigationButtonColor,
                    size: 35.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.20),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectPage = Pages.folder;
                      index = 1;
                      print(index);
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.folder,
                    color: selectPage == Pages.folder
                        ? kActiveBottomNavigationButtonColor
                        : kInactiveBottomNavigationButtonColor,
                    size: 35.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

her can you see if i tap on some of the tow buttons the index variable change the value to 0(if i tap the home IconButton) or 1(if i tap the folder IconButton)

the index number that i change is on the top from the code and i use them to change the number of the Array in the List what i use in the "body: page[index]".

anyone know why the body dosen't update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating `CustomBottomNavigationBar` (updating because of `StatefulWidget`) but `Home` is `StatelessWidget`. So in order to update the Home page, you need to convert it to `StatefulWidget`(simple case). Also, it would be not to use global variable, use callback instead.

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> page = [
      const HomeScreen(),
      const Text("ss"),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: page[index],
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(
        callback: (i) {
          setState(() {
            index = i;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int index) callback;
  const CustomBottomNavigationBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.callback,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> createState() =>
      _CustomBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _CustomBottomNavigationBarState extends State<CustomBottomNavigationBar> {
  Pages selectPage = Pages.home;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return SizedBox(
      width: size.width,
      height: 80.0,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            heightFactor: 0.71,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: 1.25,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                elevation: 0.1,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: size.width,
            height: 80.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    widget.callback(0);
                    setState(() {
                      selectPage = Pages.home;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    color: selectPage == Pages.home
                        ? kActiveBottomNavigationButtonColor
                        : kInactiveBottomNavigationButtonColor,
                    size: 35.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.20),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    widget.callback(1);
                    setState(() {
                      selectPage = Pages.folder;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.folder,
                    color: selectPage == Pages.folder
                        ? kActiveBottomNavigationButtonColor
                        : kInactiveBottomNavigationButtonColor,
                    size: 35.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change the `List<Widget> page =` based on your data

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50625777/10157127)