# What happens when onChanged is triggered on a TextField? What is a callback?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problems following step by step what happens when `onChanged` is triggered on my `TextField`. Especially, I have a problem understanding where and why the variable value gets its actual value in the following example.

Example:

```
class felder extends StatefulWidget {
  felder({super.key});
  String textFieldName = "";

  @override
  State<felder> createState() => _felderState();
}

class _felderState extends State<felder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          obscureText: false,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name'),
          onChanged: (value) => widget.textFieldName = value,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How I always imagined it: I think flutter passes a `function` in the background, which has a parameter value, that has the content of the `TextField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Actually `TextField` is a widget that has its own state.
- Whenever user types something, the value in a `TextField`
  changes.
- At that time, a callback is fired from the `TextField`.
- The changed value is also passed along with the
  callback.
- Using `onChanged: (value){ print(value); }` , we can
  get the value from that callback and use it as per our needs.

From `TextField` source code,

The text field calls the [onChanged] callback whenever the user changes the text in the field. If the user indicates that they are done typing in the field (e.g., by pressing a button on the soft keyboard), the text field calls the [onSubmitted] callback.

---

To get the value from a `TextField`, you can also use `TexteditingController`.

First declare `TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();`.

Then inside your `TextField`, add the controller like this

```
TextField(
  controller: controller,
),
```

Then to get the value from controller, you can use `controller.value.text`.

Comment: Alright that does make sense for me now, but I struggle a bit in understanding what exactly a callback means.

Comment: Watch this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWlPwj1Pp7U

Answer (score 1):

#### What is a callback?

From [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-working-with-callback-functions/):

> Callback is basically a function or a method that we pass as an
> argument into another function or a method to perform an action. In
> the simplest words, we can say that Callback or VoidCallback are used
> while sending data from one method to another and vice-versa

#### Creating a callback

To create your own callback, you can use [`ValueChanged`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueChanged.html).

**Code example:**

Let's create our own button, that when the `onChanged` is called, it will give us a new `value`:

```dart
class ButtonChange extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
  ButtonChange({Key? key, required this.value, required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ButtonChange> createState() => _ButtonChangeState();
}

class _ButtonChangeState extends State<ButtonChange> {
  bool _isToggled = false;
  void toggle() {
    setState(() {
      _isToggled = !_isToggled;
    });
    widget.onChanged(_isToggled);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: toggle,
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _isToggled ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var _value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ButtonChange(
            value: _value,
            onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() {
                  _value = value;
                })),
        Text('$_value')
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Complete example**

You can run/paste this example in your editor, and take a look:

```
const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var _value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ButtonChange(
            value: _value,
            onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() {
                  _value = value;
                })),
        Text('$_value')
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ButtonChange extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
  ButtonChange({Key? key, required this.value, required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ButtonChange> createState() => _ButtonChangeState();
}

class _ButtonChangeState extends State<ButtonChange> {
  bool _isToggled = false;
  void toggle() {
    setState(() {
      _isToggled = !_isToggled;
    });
    widget.onChanged(_isToggled);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: toggle,
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _isToggled ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### See also

[How to pass callback in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625777/how-to-pass-callback-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

##### What's in onChanged [Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html) ?

```
ValueChanged<String>? onChanged
```

> `onChanged` is of type `ValueChanged<String>` and is called when the user initiates a change to the TextField's value: when they have inserted or deleted text.

This callback doesn't run when the `TextField's text` is changed programmatically, via the `TextField's controller`. Typically it isn't necessary to be notified of such changes, since they're initiated by the app itself.

---

#### What is Callback ?

If we go by definition, the `Callback` is a `function` or a `method` which we pass as an `argument` into another `function` or `method` and can perform an action when we require it.

###### For Example, if you are working in any app and if you want any change in any value then what would you do?

Here you are in a dilemma that what you want to change either `state()` or a simple `value/values`. If you need to change states then you have various state-changing techniques but if you want to change simple values then you will use `Callback`.

Refer [this](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/working-with-callback-in-flutter-89dc207cba37) article to understand the callback on event of textChange this will surely make you understand the core behind the mechanism