# how to create custom filter chip widget as it onSelect requires argument in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have used FilterChip and using it many screens...but to avoid duplicate and lengthy codes i want to create customFilterChip widget with only three properties

onSelect method
label String
isSelected bool

but i dont know how to deal with onSelect method while creating final method...

```
class CustomFilterChipWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSelected;
  final String lable;
  //how declare function  onSelect;
  const CustomFilterChipWidget({Key? key,required this.isSelected,required this.lable,required this.onSelect}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FilterChip(
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        showCheckmark: false,
        selectedColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: StadiumBorder(
          side: BorderSide(
              width: isSelected ? 2 : 0,
              color: isSelected
                  ? Colors.blue
                  : Colors.grey),
        ),
        selected: isSelected,
        label: Text(
            lable,),
        onSelected: onSelect);
  }
}
```

as in filter chip

it requires value in argument

```
onSelected: (value) {
            
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close: first, accept a function `onSelected`:

```dart
class CustomFilterChipWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSelected;
  final String label;
  final Function(bool) onSelected;
```

and then call it:

```dart
 onSelected: (bool value) {
        onSelected(value);
      },
```

The complete code will be:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CustomFilterChipWidget(
              isSelected: isSelected,
              label: 'Value is $isSelected',
              onSelected: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  isSelected = !isSelected;
                });
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomFilterChipWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isSelected;
  final String label;
  final Function(bool) onSelected;
  CustomFilterChipWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.isSelected,
      required this.label,
      required this.onSelected})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FilterChip(
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      showCheckmark: false,
      selectedColor: Colors.white,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shape: StadiumBorder(
        side: BorderSide(
            width: isSelected ? 2 : 0,
            color: isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
      ),
      selected: isSelected,
      label: Text(
        label,
      ),
      onSelected: (bool value) {
        onSelected(value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

##### See also

- [How to pass callback in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625777/how-to-pass-callback-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks...this is what i need how to pass callback..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can literally create your own version of a widget, by redefining the widget itself, for that, you just need to extend the original class, and pay attention to all the required properties that FilterChip needs:

```
class CustomFilteredChip extends FilterChip {
     const CustomFilteredChip({super.key, required super.label, required 
     super.onSelected});

     // here you can override any method that you need
     // like the build, onSelected, etc
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) { /*  */ }

     @override
     ValueChanged<bool>? onSelected() { /*  */ }
}
```

If you are not sure what properties you can access or modify, navigate to the `FilterChip` (CTRL+Left Click on the class name in Visual Studio Code on Windows), and you can check all the properties, data types, and methods of the class.